# Extracting multiple date entries for an user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table , example of the header:
userid, product, product2, activation_day, deactivation_day

How can I extract all users lets say, who have different activation_days and different deactivation_days. Because that user activated his product, lets say on the 21012021 and then deactivates his product on 21032021 and then it comes back and activates his product on 01052021 and now it's an active customer. So for him deactivation_day its 31122099.

BasicallY i want the following output:

```
userid, product, product2, activation_day, deactivation_day 
1xx1    aa       aa2       21012021        21032021
1xx1    aa       aa2       01052021        31122099
```

Comment: Two columns contain the product, so your question is really unclear.  Your question specifies that you only want users, but the results have five columns, so it is not explained.  I am quite confused.  *Sample* data as well as desired results would help.  And what is the data type of the date columns?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed those 2 columns are confusing. it should go like this the final output:   userid, product, product2, activation_day, deactivation_day 
1xx1    aa       aa2       21012021                                             21032021
1xx1    bb       bb2       01052021                                             31122099

Answer (score 0):

Are you just after an `EXISTS`?

```sql
SELECT * --Replace with columns
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.YourTable E
              WHERE E.userid = YT.userid
                AND E.activation_day <> YT.activation_day
                AND E.deactivation_day <> YT.deactivation_day);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you are really asking for are users that have the same two products but with gaps in the time periods.

Assuming that your dates are actually stored as dates, one method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.userid = t.userid and
                    t2.product = t.product and
                    t2.product2 = t.product2 and
                    (t2.activation_day > t.deactivation_day or
                     t2.deactivation_day < t.activation_day
                    );
```